# Проверка данных при импорте из Excel

Tags: c#

Есть таблица Excel содержащая в первом столбец название (условно Марка автомобиля), во втором столбце Модель автомобиля. В первом столбце названия повторяются. Как организовать проверку данных по первому столбцу

Comment: Какую проверку? На наличие повторений? На наличие данных? 
Опишите подробнее, с примерами кода, как вы себе это представляете

Comment: Данные из файла необходимо импортировать в базу. Запись производится по значениям. Если в первом столбце найдена новая запись она записывается, если запись уже есть в базе, то записываем данные из второго столбца.
Файл выглядит следующим образом:
ТагАЗ Tager
ТагАЗ Vega
УАЗ         2206
УАЗ         2360 / Cargo
В конечном итоге в базе должно быть только две записи ТагАЗ и УАЗ         , содержащие в себе 2 записи моделей.

Comment: Ну так стройте алгоритм - реализовывайте.

Comment: `в базе должно быть только две записи ТагАЗ и УАЗ , содержащие в себе 2 записи моделей.` Записи в записях? это Вас кто-то обманул...